# What routes needs to be added

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

My  host machine has IP `192.168.3.x` and my guest virtual machine has `90.34.4.x`
I cannot ping from guest to host and vice versa. My host machine can reach other networks. What route needs to be added on to guest so i can ping host and all other subnets which my host can ping.
My guest virtual machine has Red Hat Linux. Can you help me with the command.

Comment: What kind of networking adapter is your VM using?

Comment: Is your VM network NATed or bridged, and are you using a firewall on either machine?